# How do I get the Access-Token-Secret in QuickBooks?

Tags: php, oauth, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I have PHP SDK files and facing the error without `Access-Token-Secret`.

> Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidTokenException: [0]: Access token secret
>   cannot be null or empty.

Where I can't get this `Access-Token-Secret` in my QuickBooks trial account.
I can able to get *Access Token, Consumer Key, Consumer Secret*.

I am a new of QuickBooks and also now I am try to configure.Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go through the OAuth flow to get the access token.

Click the [Connect to QuickBooks] button. This kicks off the OAuth flow. The access token is handed back to you as part of the redirect back to your site. Documentation:

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0100_essentials/0085_develop_quickbooks_apps/0004_authentication_and_authorization/connect_from_within_your_app

Comment: It's very useful..Thanks!.

Comment: hi @KeithPalmerJr the link you posted results to 404

Comment: Updated the link. Google search is your friend.